# multivariate gaussian integral with linear constraint

Tags: real-analysis, integration, gaussian-integral

I am interested in the calculation of the multivariate gaussian integral
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\mathbb R^N} \mathrm d x_1\cdots \mathrm d x_N \; \prod_{j=1}^Ne^{-\frac{x_j^2}{2\sigma_j^2}}\delta\left(x-\sum_{l=1}^N c_l x_l\right)
\end{equation*}
for a set of $c_l\in\mathbb R$. Is there a way to solve the integral with this linear constraint? If so, how?
As a simple separation of variables does not apply anymore, I would guess that a smart change of variables could be a way to tackle the calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically one uses the representation $\delta(f(x))={1\over 2\pi}\int dk e^{i k f(x)}$

Comment: I see, that's convenient. Then I guess it's a matter of closing the square for the $N$ integrals in $x_j$; there's only an additional integration over a simple exponential in $k$

Comment: Actually, you will find that the integration will be an exponential in $k^2$ ( a Gaussian)